# Express Mongo call not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I'm trying to get objects stored in a Mongo collection using node+express in the following way:

```
router.get('/api/articles/:page',function(req,res){
var x = {}
  Article.find({},function(err,arts){
    res.json(arts);
  }).limit(10).skip(page*10).sort({timestamp:-1});
});
```

But it throws an error: Cant set headers after they are set. This eror has started occuring ever since I included the `skip(page*10)` function in the database retrieval.

Comment: Is that your complete service code or did you remove something?

Comment: @Mahesh It is the code to retrieve 10 articles sorted by their timestamps and skipping 10 articles depending on the page user asked for. For example if I want latest 10 articles I'll call `'/api/articles/0'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/api/articles/:page',function(req,res){
  var page = (typeof(req.params.page) === undefined) ? 0 : parseInt(req.params.page);
  Article.find({})
         .limit(10).
         .skip(page*10)
         .sort({timestamp:-1})
         .exec(function(err,arts){
            if(err)
               res.json(err);
            else
               res.json(arts);
         });
});
```

Comment: It gives an error saying `ReferenceError: page is not defined`

Comment: @AyushGupta anything in `req.params` will return a string. You need to cast numerics: `.skip((typeof(req.params.page) === undefined) ? 0 : parseInt(req.params.page))`